# Hide Wordpress “wp-admin” dashboard to User IDS

Tags: user-access

Is there a way to remove & redirect any users of a site from accessing

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/
```

Unless there id is one, i have seen some examples floating around the ask if admin-ajax is being used if so redirect. how ever this is not approach i wish to make as im using admin ajax on the front end for some admins. i just don't wish them to see anything to do with the backend of wordpress.

Only userid 1 should have access to wp-admin.

Comment: What is the purpose of restricting users on this site? Can you just make all the users without access be Subscribers?

Comment: Restrict wp-admin by user role is an easier option.

Comment: you can use this plugin wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful plugin dedicated for this task called : [Remove Dashboard Access](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/) which allows you to remove direct access to wp-admin for all users except the admins.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply,
Thats not bad, how ever the only admin account i wish to have access is User ID 1,

Because i have admins using admin-ajax for frontend side of things.
If i restrict them to a subscriber or something else they will not be able to use the admin-ajax functions.

There is really no need for them to use the wp-admin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

As well you can try using WPS Hide Login plugin( https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```php
if ( is_admin() && 1 !== absint( get_current_user_id() ) && ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( '/' );
    exit;
}
```